# vbscript - modify shortcut if it exists

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to modify shortcut (by deleting old one and creating new one) to desktop, the script first checks if file exists, if it exists, it should modify it. Tried this without any luck. It works when I remove the file exist check, so the problem should be on the file exists check. Here is my code:

```
Set wsc = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If (wsc.FileExists(wsc.SpecialFolders("desktop") & "\Google Chrome.LNK")) Then

Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set lnk = fso.CreateShortcut(fso.SpecialFolders("desktop") & "\Google Chrome.LNK")
lnk.targetpath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
lnk.Arguments = "http://www.google.com"
lnk.save

End If
```

What is the correct way to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your objects are mixed up. You are calling `FSO` `wsc` and `wscript.shell` `fso`. You are using `wscript.shell` before creating it.

```
Set wsc = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

If (wsc.FileExists(wsc.SpecialFolders("desktop") & "\Google Chrome.LNK")) Then
  Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

I've swapped the objects to what you intended rather that what you typed.

Here's all 5 errors fixed, plus the one logic error (you only created shortcut if it already existed):

```
Set wsc = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If (fso.FileExists(wsc.SpecialFolders("desktop") & "\Google Chrome.LNK")) = false Then

    Set lnk = wsc.CreateShortcut(wsc.SpecialFolders("desktop") & "\Google Chrome.LNK")
    lnk.targetpath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
    lnk.Arguments = "http://www.google.com"
    lnk.save

End If
```

Comment: As I said in my answer you are assigning "Scripting.FileSystemObject" to WSC. But WSC is being used as a wscript.shell object. And vice versa, assigning "wscript.shell" to FSO and using it as a file system object. Looking at the names wsc has an fso object in it, and fso has a wscript.shell (wsc) object in it. You've just typed the wrong object in both CreateObject. Swap them.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but still doesnt work. Have you tried that ?